# $D(T^*T)$ is a core for $T$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a closed densely-defined operator, then I want to show that $D(T^*T)$ is a core for $T$. This means the closure of $T|_{D_{T^*T}}$ is $T$ again. It is easy to notice that this is equivalent to showing that $T \subset (T|_{D_{T^*T}})^{**}.$

You are btw. allowed to use that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the underlying Hilbert space. To say that $\mathscr{D}=\mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T)$ is a core for $T$ means that the closure of the graph of $T|_{\mathscr{D}}$ is the same as the the graph of $T$. If that is not the case, then there exists $x \in \mathcal{D}(T)\setminus\{0\}$ such that that $\langle x,Tx\rangle\in \mathcal{G}(T)\subset X\times X$ is orthogonal to the graph $\mathcal{G}(T|_{\mathscr{D}})$ of the restriction. That is,
$$
          (x,y)+(Tx,Ty) = 0,\;\;\; y \in \mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T), \\
          (x,y+T^{\star}Ty)=0,\;\;\; y \in \mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T).
$$
However, because $T^{\star}T$ is selfadjoint and positive, then $I+T^{\star}T$ is surjective, which gives the desired contradiction that $x=0$. Hence, $\overline{\mathcal{G}(T|_{\mathscr{D}})}=\mathcal{G}(T)$.

Comment: are you aware of an elementary proof that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint? All proofs I found so far use the Friedrich extension. Is it also possible to proof this from the start, just using that an operator $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $ker(A \pm i)=\{0\}$ and $A$ is closed, or $ran(A \pm i) = H$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514504/show-self-adjointness-elementary I opened a new question for this.